# How can I concatenate/merge two columns with different length?

Tags: google-sheets

Consider:

[image]

I'm new to Google Sheets. I have a column(E) with the date and another with a session(F). I want to merge them into one column with each date and different session, just like the first few rows in column C.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please edit your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate values in two columns on a row-by-row-basis, use `to_text()` and the `&` concatenation operator, like this:

```
=arrayformula( if( len(E2:E), to_text(E2:E) & " " & to_text(F2:F), F2:F ) )
```

To get the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two columns, use this pattern:

```
=arrayformula( 
  flatten( 
    unique(filter(to_text(E2:E) & " ", len(E2:E))) 
    & 
    transpose(filter(to_text(F2:F), len(F2:F))) 
  )
)
```

These formulas should go to row `2` of a free column.

Comment: that's exactly what i want. thank you so much!